# `$scope` data not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

By default, I am having a `message` in my scope. when i call my `login` page, i am not getting the `message` in the html.

i don't know what i miss here, any one figure-out please?

my app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myNewApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl :   'js/scripts/views/login.html',
                controller:     'js/scripts/controllers/loginCont.js'
            })
            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'controllers/userRegisterCont.js'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode('true');

    }])
```

my lognCont.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myNewApp')
    .controller('loginCont', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Welcome";
    }]);
```

my login html :

```
<h1>I am login here! {{message}}</h1>
```

what else missing here? any one help me

since i use `html5` support still the url is with `#` `http://localhost:3000/#/login`

Comment: check ng-app and ng-controller is properly included or not..

Comment: @Ved, let me check. and why my location url is like this : `since i use html5 support still the url is with # http://localhost:3000/#/login`

Comment: register controller is your default?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury, what you mean?

Comment: Please post your complete HTML code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the name of the registered controller as a String, or the controller function by itself.

So this:

```
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl :   'js/scripts/views/login.html',
            controller:     'loginCont'
        })
```

should work

Comment: so the controller need to attached with html page? and is it require further implementation in `inject`?

Comment: @3gwebtrain You need to attach the controller to your module, which you already did. And then off course, load the javascript file in your html page.

Comment: yes, thanks. and why my location bar with `#` still i use html5 support? 
`http://localhost:3000/#/login` - i expect `http://localhost:3000/login` - how to sort?

Comment: @3gwebtrain replace $locationProvider.html5Mode('true'); with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and try.

Comment: When i type as "http://localhost:3000/login" - i am getting error as `Cannot GET /login ` , in case if am not enter anything after `http://localhost:3000/` - it direct to `http://localhost:3000/login` and works properly. what i missing still?

Comment: yes, that works. but as a user no one can type such a way right? then what is mean to use `html5` support here?